# Is 'ex' of 'extinct' pronounced differently from that of 'exactly'?

Tags: pronunciation

This question below is from my English book exercise:

> Choose the word whose underlined part is pronounced differently from that of the other words
>
> a. **ex**actly
>   b. **ex**ist
>   c. **ex**haust
>   d. **ex**tinct

(Because I couldn't underline the part of each word in this post, I made it bold)

After trying reading aloud each word a few times, I couldn't notice any differences of the above 'ex' parts. Then I looked it up in Oxford Dictionary and it showed each word's phonetic transciption like this:

> a. **ex**actly   [/**ɪɡ**ˈzæktli/](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/exactly?q=exactly)
>   b. **ex**ist   [/**ɪɡ**ˈzɪst/](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/exist?q=exist)
>   c. **ex**haust   [/**ɪɡ**ˈzɔːst/](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/exhaust_1?q=exhaust)
>   d. **ex**tinct  [/**ɪk**ˈstɪŋkt/](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/extinct?q=extinct)

If the /ɪɡ/ and /ɪk/ are at the end of the word, like 'big' or 'tick', I can see the differences and pronounce them easily. However, in the exercise, it seems to me that the /ɡ/ and /k/ of all the words are canceled or silent.

Could you advise me on whether I'm correct or not in this case?

Comment: Keep in mind that pronunciation can vary a lot by region. "Extinct" and "exact" would sound fine to me whether pronounced with `/k/` or `/g/`.

Comment: Extinct is the different word, like exterior and exlamation, explanation.

Comment: "However, in the exercise, it seems to me that the /ɡ/ and /k/ of all the words are canceled or silent." - I'm not sure what you mean by "canceled or silent", because they definitely make a sound that is very important to the pronunciation of the words.  If you just mean that they don't make a difference...they are pronounced similarly, but not exactly the same.  "Eggs" and "ex" should sound different.  As @TonyK says, one is voiced and one is unvoiced.

Answer (score 3):

A native English speaker pronounces *extinct* differently from *egg stinked* (yes I know, that should be *egg stank*). *extinct* is pronounced with an unvoiced /k/ sound, and *egg stinked* with a voiced /g/ sound.

As you remark, there would be hardly any difference in this context if voicing were the only distinction. But in most dialects of English, a syllable-final unvoiced consonant preceded by a vowel is *pre-glottalized*. In some dialects, notably Cockney, the consonant (especially /t/) can disappear entirely, and all that's left is the glottal stop: "Wha' a lo'" for "What a lot".

See the [Wikipedia article on Glottalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottalization) for a discussion of this.

Answer (score 2):

There are some general rules for the pronunciation of *ex-*:

- It's pronounced /ks/ when it has primary stress as in *execute, exile, extra* etc.
- When it's unstressed, then its pronunciation depends on the following sound:

  - if the following sound is a vowel or another voiced sound, it's pronounced /gz/ as in *exact, exist, exhaust, exhilarate* etc.
  - if the following sound is voiceless, it's /ks/ as in *expire, explain, extreme, expunge* etc.

'Exact' belongs to the first sub-category in the second category, while 'extinct' belongs to the second one in the second category.

There may be exceptions, however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are pronounced differently. The '*ex*' in 'exact' sounds more like 'eggs'.

There is a reason for this - many words use 'ex' as a prefix. It comes from the Latin meaning '*out*'. For example 'exhale' means to breathe out, 'extract' means to pull out, and 'extinct' means to die out.

That isn't the case with 'exact' - it comes from the Latin *exactus*, which in its entirety means 'precise', so the word has a different etymology.

It is no surprise that we over-pronounce 'ex-' in words where it acts as a prefix because it often acts to negate a word, for example, 'ex-girlfriend', or 'ex-wife'.